# SSIS package store from Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, ssis, package, jobs

I create an SSIS package from visual studio 2013, and it works, now I want to create a job (it's the first time that I create one) in SSMS (sql server 2008) under step , SSIS package store it's empty.
Could you please help me because I don't know how to create a package?
PS I don't find DTS folder under sql server folder.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> SSIS package store it's empty

The package store is empty because you likely haven't created an SSIS catalog and haven't deployed your project to the SSIS Package store.

It looks like you are on SQL Server 2008, so if you are on SSIS 2008, [use this MSDN article to deploy your project](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140117%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you are on SSIS 2012 or greater, then see this detailed step-by-step walkthrough on how to setup and deploy your SSIS Packages. [SSIS Projects: Setup, Project Creation and Deployment](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-2012-projects-setup-project-creation-and-deployment/)

Comment: when I try to create package, I have this message (I have the right to read / write on DTS/Packages) : TITLE: Package Installation Wizard
------------------------------

Could not create the directory "d:\Apps\Microsoft SQL Server (x86)\110\DTS\Packages\Integration Services Project1". Access to the path 'd:\Apps\Microsoft SQL Server (x86)\110\DTS\Packages\Integration Services Project1' is denied.

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: I m running it as admin, I think the problem is VS 2013 SSDT-bi I found it start working with SQL server 2014 , In my case I have SQL Server 2012